# Why doesn't this open when I log in with my Firebase log in? SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

```
 Button(action: {
                          signIn()
                    
               }){
                  Text("Sign In")
                        .font(.title)
                       .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 200)
                        .cornerRadius(100.00)
                        .frame(height: 20)
                       .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                       .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
                   .background(Color.blue)
                      .cornerRadius(5.0)

                }.alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text(alertTitle), message: Text(error), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok!")))
                }
```

THE SIGN IN FUNCTION BEING CALLED BELOW! This func and whatnot I think signs me in (I see in my firebase log) but it doesn't transfer me to the next screen. I tried a navlink but it lets you press sign in then go to Home Screen no matter what.

func signIn() {

```
    if let error = errorCheck() {
        
        self.error = error
        self.showingAlert = true
        
        return
    }
    
    AuthService.signIn(email: email, password: password, onSuccess: {
        (user) in
        self.clear()
        
    }) {
        (errorMessage) in
        print("Error \(errorMessage)")
        self.error = errorMessage
        self.showingAlert = true
        return
        
        
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: I think what you want is a fullScreenCover. 
So add a new State variable and add .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $navigate) {
    YourView()} and in the button where you wanna navigate to the next screen add navigate.toggle(). Let me know if this is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your view to activate the next screen;

```
@State var activate = false
```

and add this to your view, for example after the button:

```
NavigationLink("", destination: Text("the next screen"), isActive: $activate)
```

then add this to your func signIn() just after self.clear() to change the activate state.

```
activate = true
```

assuming func signIn() is also in your view.

Note your view must have NavigationView for NavigationLink to work.